# Extend MVC Api Controller Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Right now I have two controllers, one for MVC another one for API.

```
// API
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Users <- works great
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers() {}

    // **Not sure if this one is correct!**
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsersChart([FromURI]int id)
    {
        return Ok(repo.GetUsersChart(id));
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand on how to call my Charts generation api within C# code with HttpWebRequest?

Something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest createChartRequest =
WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/api/Users/Chart/?id={1}", ServerUrl, 1));
```

would give me HTTP 500 error.

Update:

Here is routing configuration:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: updated according to request.

Comment: just a sanity check - your variable ServerUrl doesn't happen to have a trailing slash ( '/' ) correct?

Comment: nope, it's all good, I've tried the other GetUsers API and it works fine.

Comment: Try `{0}/api/Users/UsersChart/{1}` for your format string.

Comment: you might need to decorate your GetUsersChart() method with [HttpGet]

Comment: Sorry, previous comment should have said "Try `{0}/api/Users/{1}`" for your format string. That should work, since it has the matching route pattern. Decorating with `[HttpGet]` shouldn't be necessary since your method name starts with "Get". If you want to use the action name in the route, use `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` for your route template. Also see [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

A response code of 500 means that you have some error in your API action. It has nothing to do with your route or how you're requesting it. If this is in development, inspect the response in your browser's developer tools and you should be able to see a description of the actual server error there. If this is in production, you'll need to log the error somehow such as with ELMAH so you can see what's causing the issue.